# Django-extjs Url Data

Tags: django, extjs

Newbie question here.

I am trying to use the django-extjs library in my django app from (https://github.com/softmechanics/django-extjs).  I need an array grid and extjs seems to offer the cleanest interface.

I was able to get a basic array-grid operational based on static data. But I am having difficulty integrating the grid into my own model.  I am getting a 404 error.

[22/Nov/2010 22:22:09] "GET /appname/example_model?_dc=1290489729717 HTTP/1.1" 404 3519

I am confused by the url information set ("?_dc=1290489729717").  I don't understand what this data means or where the django-extjs package is adding it.  Is there a way I can (or should) elegantly use this data in my django app? The documentation isn't clear why or how this data is there.

```
1.  What is the "?_dc=1290489729717" represent?  
2.  Where is django-extjs package adding it to my url? 
3.  Are there any good example implementations beyond the package?
```

Thanks!

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a parameter that Ext JS adds automatically to requests to avoid caching.  It's just an arbitrary random number to make the url unique.  `Ext.data.Connection` has a [disableCaching](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Connection.html#cfg-Ext.data.Connection-disableCaching) config that is true by default for GET requests, but you can turn it off by passing false.  Not sure how your Django lib has that wrapped, but that's what to look for (it might be happening via Ext.Ajax too, which is a singleton Connection wrapper).